# Flutter - SwitchListTile - DRY code

Tags: dart, flutter

Complete newbie, so bear with me. Just a question on how I could refactor my code using the DRY principle. I'm sure it can be done on such a simple example so here goes.... My code below shows three 'switchListTiles'. I've managed to work out how to create 3 switchListTiles on top of one another, and also how to get them to turn on/off individually. Its just that this means I'm creating the following function 3 times:

```
bool _value3 = false;

void _onChanged3(bool value3) {
    setState(() {
      _value3 = value3;
    });
  }
```

I'm sure there is a way I could change this so I don't have the same code three times. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated 
Many thanks in advance

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
      runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: "Switch Widget Demo",
        home: new MyApp(),
      ));
    }

    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }

    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

      bool _value = false;

      void _onChanged(bool value) {
        setState(() {
          _value = value;
        });
      }

      bool _value2 = false;

      void _onChanged2(bool value2) {
        setState(() {
          _value2 = value2;
        });
      }

      bool _value3 = false;

      void _onChanged3(bool value3) {
        setState(() {
          _value3 = value3;
        });
      }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Switch Demo"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[

            Switch(value: _value,
              onChanged: (bool value) {_onChanged(value);}),
            SwitchListTile(value: _value,
              title: Text("Click Me"),
              activeColor: Colors.red,
              secondary: Icon(Icons.home),
              subtitle: Text("For my small print"),
              onChanged: (bool value) {_onChanged(value);}),

            SwitchListTile(value: _value2,
                title: Text("Click Me Again Please"),
                activeColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                secondary: Icon(Icons.perm_identity),
                onChanged: (bool value2) {_onChanged2(value2);}),

            SwitchListTile(value: _value3,
                title: Text("And Again Please"),
                activeColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                subtitle: Text("Some more small print"),
                secondary: Icon(Icons.person),
                onChanged: (bool value) {_onChanged3(value);}),


          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How about add an index to your _onChanged: _onChanged(boolean value, int index)?

Comment: You can also write a method to create SwitchListTile and call it 3 times

Answer (score 4):

You just need to refactor the `SwitchListTiles` into its separate class, then make `List<SwitchListTiles>` in the parent widget.

Here I create 20 of them with lesser code:

[image]

```
class MySwitchListTilesContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      body: ListView(
        children: List.generate(20, (i)=>MySwitchListTile(

        )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class MySwitchListTile extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _MySwitchListTileState createState() => new _MySwitchListTileState();
}

class _MySwitchListTileState extends State<MySwitchListTile> {
  bool _v = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return  SwitchListTile(
      value:_v,
      onChanged: (value)=>setState((){
        _v=value;
      }),

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for the response (both of you). Also thanks for the code update Aziza. Seems like its what I wanted only issue is how does one go about individualising each 'SwitchListTile' (i.e. different name, subtitle etc.) ??? Also something else came to mind how would one go abouts assigning a different 'onChanged' method to each one of these - Again thanks for your help

Comment: I know this is an old question, but if you're still wondering, you can create variables for the MySwitchListTile and pass them through the constructor. Depends on your needs but then you'll pass these values to your _MySwitchListTileState class and assign them to the respective properties (e.g pass a String called title and assign it to the string of a Text widget which you'll create inside the SwitchListTile title property). Also I believe you could use a ValueSetter to be passed to the onChanged